# How to restrict my mobile app with AllowedApplications values of Airwatch SDK Profile Restrictions?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, airwatch, airwatchsdk

I am developing an mdm application that listens to SDK profiles from Workspace One UEM/Airwatch console and takes relevant actions. (Group & Settings -> All Settings -> Apps -> Settings and Policies -> Profiles -> Add Profile -> SDK Profile)
For example, in my application, the picture taken with the camera is uploaded, but if "Enable Camera" is set to "False" in SDK Profile -> Restrictions settings, I prevent the camera from opening from my application and show the appropriate message to the user.

However, I'm having trouble with the "Restrict documents to be opened in following apps" part. In my application, I saw that the "AllowedApplications" array came in the AWRestrictionsPayload object. For testing, I serialized this array to json and I wrote it to txt. When I look at this txt file, I see that there is an integer value for the applications added to the allowed application. But how can I make sense of which application these integer values ​​correspond to?

```
var profile = $"Allowed Applications: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(restrictionPayload.AllowedApplications)}";
Helper.AWLog(profile);
```

The value I see in the txt is:

> "Allowed Applications: [{"value":10768205216},{"value":10768205264}]"

In my application, there is a feature such as share files with Whatsapp/Mail/Message etc. I think I should restrict to "Restrict documents to be opened in following apps" option. But I didn't understand how to do this. How do I make sense of this value or make this constraint?

Thanks in advance.